# SQL Server to CSV character encoding

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, character-encoding

I have a SQL Server database extract I'm doing.

At the beginning of my program, I have:

```
ini_set('mssql.charset','cp1250');
```

My database calls do not do anything special.

I'm only call the following methods:

```
mssql_connect, mssql_select_db, mssql_query, mssql_fetch_object, 
mssql_next_result and mssql_close.
```

When I print the output of my export on screen, all the characters look fine. When I export `fputcsv()` into a csv file, I get a ton of <92> and <93> characters (this is the way that they look when I use a terminal to read them). When I open the file using Excel, they look like ì, í and î

This is causing major problems. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks but it turns out that the problem isn't with the encoding so much as it is with the fact that my fputcsv() call actually was not specifying a delimiter. I chose "\t" for the delim and everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

try to convert encoding into utf8

```
iconv('cp1250', 'utf-8', $text);
```

also print this:

```
var_dump(iconv_get_encoding('all'));
```

Comment: output of var_dump: array(3) { ["input_encoding"]=> string(10) "ISO-8859-1" ["output_encoding"]=> string(10) "ISO-8859-1" ["internal_encoding"]=> string(10) "ISO-8859-1" } 

Output of iconv: Äô characters everywhere in the csv.